# Kendo UI control like Select2

Tags: kendo-ui

I really like the UI of the select2 control.  However, I really want to use the kendo datasource for binding.  The select2 control is a merge of autocomplete and dropdownlist.  I want to have the name value pair, which autocomplete doesn't give you. The combobox is close, however that allows new entry, which I don't want.

I'm willing to make my own control and contribute it to the Labs projects.  However, I'd like some advice on getting started. My question is, which control would I start with as a base?  Any hints or advice to get started? Doesn't seem like it would be a large change from the existing controls.

thanks,

~ Paul

Comment: Did you consider Kendo UI multiselect? it is not Select2 but maybe is enough for what you are looking for.

Comment: @pwelter34  Isn't my solution close to what you want?I was just curious to know whether It worked for you or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Combobox` and add functionality to `change event` such that if it's new entry (selected index: -1), set empty value.
Check   T-shirt Fabric combobox  on this fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/sanjeev537/9ZNMJ/

Comment: Html.Kendo().ComboxBox is an excellent select2 alternative for Html.Kendo().DropDownList(). I especially like that I can swap it in easily and only change .OptionLabel to .PlaceHolder. It doesn't do full text searches though..

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiselect component https://www.telerik.com/kendo-vue-ui/components/dropdowns/multiselect/